# Add Paragraph via itext.Layout.Document.ShowTextAligned on first Page only

Tags: powershell, itext

I' m trying to add rotated, border Text to the First Page of an PDF Document with itext7 and powershell.

I found a good solutian [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339560/add-a-text-on-an-existing-pdf-document-by-appending-something-after-the-pdf-cont/65397533#65397533) from [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) and ported it to Powershell:

```
function SetRotatedTextStamp([String]$InFile, [String]$OutFile) {
  [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]     $Reader   = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new($InFile)
  [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]     $Writer   = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($OutFile)
  [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]   $PDFDoc   = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($Reader, $Writer, $([iText.Kernel.Pdf.StampingProperties]::new()).UseAppendMode()) 
  [iText.Layout.Document]          $Doc      = [iText.Layout.Document]::new($PDFDoc)
  [iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph] $pCurPara = [iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new("Hello World")
    
  $pCurPara.SetWidth(100)
  $pCurPara.SetBorder([iText.Layout.Borders.SolidBorder]::new([iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb]::new(255, 0, 0), 2))
  $pCurPara.SetRotationAngle([Math]::PI / 4)

  [iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle] $rect = $($PDFDoc.GetFirstPage()).GetCropBox()
  $Doc.ShowTextAligned($pCurPara, ($rect.GetLeft() + $rect.GetRight()) / 2,
                  ($rect.GetTop() + $rect.GetBottom()) / 2,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment]::CENTER,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment]::MIDDLE
                )
    
  $Doc.Close()
  $PDFDoc.Close()
  $Writer.Close()
  $Reader.Close()
}
```

But The Paragraph appears centered on the last page, instead of the first.
I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in my original answer I used the wrong `showTextAligned` overload which drew on the last page, not the first. As I tested with a single-page document that didn't show.

In general you have to replace

```
  $Doc.ShowTextAligned($pCurPara, ($rect.GetLeft() + $rect.GetRight()) / 2,
                  ($rect.GetTop() + $rect.GetBottom()) / 2,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment]::CENTER,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment]::MIDDLE
                )
```

by

```
  $Doc.ShowTextAligned($pCurPara, ($rect.GetLeft() + $rect.GetRight()) / 2,
                  ($rect.GetTop() + $rect.GetBottom()) / 2,
                  1,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment]::CENTER,
                  [iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment]::MIDDLE,
                  0
                )
```

to draw on the first page. The `1` is the page number; the `0` is an angle, another place where you can select text rotation.